# How to Loop through LINQ results (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, linq, foreach

I've got some code to try and loop through LINQ results, but it doesn't seem to be working.

HERE'S THE CODE

```
    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        ''# the page contenttype is plain text'
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"

        ''# store the querystring as a variable'
        Dim qs As Nullable(Of Integer) = Integer.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("ID"), Nothing)

        ''# use the RegionsDataContext'
        Using RegionDC As New DAL.RegionsDataContext

            ''# create a (q)uery variable'
            Dim q As Object

            ''# if the querystring PID is not blank'
            ''# then we want to return results based on  the PID'
            If Not qs Is Nothing Then
                ''# that fit within the Parent ID'
                q = (From r In RegionDC.bt_Regions _
                        Where r.PID = qs _
                       Select r.Region).ToArray

                ''# now we loop through the array'
                ''# and write out the ressults'
                For Each item As DAL.bt_Region In q
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(item.Region & vbCrLf)
                Next

            End If



        End Using
    End Sub
```

HERE'S THE ERROR

> Public member 'Region' on type
>   'String' not found. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.MissingMemberException: Public
>   member 'Region' on type 'String' not
>   found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 33:                     ' and
>   write out the ressults Line 34:
>   For Each item In q Line 35:
>   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(item.Region
>   & vbCrLf) Line 36:
>   Next Line 37:
>
> Source File:
>   E:\Projects\businesstrader\App_Code\Handlers\RegionsAutoComplete.vb
>   Line: 35
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMemberException: Public member
>   'Region' on type 'String' not found.] 
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Container.GetMembers(String&
>   MemberName, Boolean ReportErrors)
>   +509081    Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String
>   MemberName, Object[] Arguments,
>   String[] ArgumentNames, Type[]
>   TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
>   +222    BT.Handlers.RegionsAutoComplete.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) in
>   E:\Projects\businesstrader\App_Code\Handlers\RegionsAutoComplete.vb:35
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +181    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +75

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is saying that the objects stored in the `bt_Regions` property are of type `String` and so they don't have the member `Region` which you're trying to access.

I would double-check what is the type of `DAL.bt_Regions` - it looks like you're assuming that it returns some class, but it seems to be returning a collection of strings (perhaps just region names?). To see what it contains, you can modify the code like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(item & vbCrLf) // to print the string
```

I would also try adding the [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs(VS.80).aspx) option (if possible), which would instruct the compiler to check this kind of errors at compile-time.

Comment: ah yes.  using "item" worked since I'm only selecting one record (which is a string) from the database.